# Steam Game (I think with a mobile version) where you play a neophyte hero who has to balance training and work against missions and a time limit

Tags: story-identification, video-games, super-hero

I think the last time I played this was 2-3 years ago, on my old computer, but I think I got it closer to 8 years ago, in some sort of software bundle, involving being a new superhero working their way up the ranks. The gameplay involved colored spheres on a hexagonal grid where you drew lines through them using the mouse. I think there were three colors, corresponding to three attributes (Strength, Mental, and Magic, maybe?) and there were occasionally "special" spheres that had additional effects, or which could not be used in a line. There were "job/training" tasks where you were just competing against a time or move limit to gain money or increase your stats, and combat ones, where I think you were accruing energy to fire off your attacks and defenses, taking turns. As you got stronger, you got access to training/work facilities that gave a higher reward, but there was also a degree to which your experience at a facility boosted your gains, so there was a tradeoff on when you "moved on". Combat encounters involved either intercepting a figure roving around the map (which I think was accompanied by a siren sound effect) which usually involved fighting one person, or "maze" setups where you had a grid of squares where you advanced through them one by one, sometimes fighting someone on a square. There was a time limit in the game, where you had to defeat the villain in a certain amount of days, and I think time both progressed real-time while playing, and also in chunks during going to work/training/encounters. I think that, at all times, losing a combat just meant lost time, and sometimes having to re-enter one of those maze battles. In general, the game was pretty tongue-in-cheek about how ridiculous superheroes can be, looking in from the outside.

At the very start of the game, you gain powers and pick your gender, name, and I think which of the three elements you focus on. There was a Rock-Paper-Scissors element to the three elements, so you couldn't really afford to focus on just one, and parts of the game got easier or harder depending on whether you were targeting the correct element. Foes and allies were represented with static images and text, no voiceovers. After getting your powers, you are mentored by "The Wizard" or someone named like that, which was a Caucasian man, I think wearing a stereotypical robe and pointed hat, with a long grey beard. I think that, as the story progressed, you uncovered some sort of corruption, maybe involving villains posing as heroes, or heroes being brainwashed into being villains.

I remember that, when I played, I found the Mental powers most useful, because one of the powers, not too far in the game, had a "Stun" chance, which could sometimes lock your opponent into being unable to do anything as you kept accruing enough energy to restun them. I also remember most of the defensive powers as not being very useful since it took an action to raise defenses that didn't last long, and seldom soaked all of the damage. The only other thing I remember about distinctive combat bits was that you often ran into non-powered criminals who only had Physical attacks involving guns and knives.

The mobile Android version, which I think I checked out, but didn't purchase, involved more of a Match-3 gameplay. Not certain if it had the same storyline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are probably thinking of [Spandex Force: Champion Rising](https://store.steampowered.com/app/380560/Spandex_Force_Champion_Rising/), which was released on Steam in 2015 and on mobile sometime before that.

From the Steam description (emphasis mine):

> What kind of hero will you be?
> In Spandex Force: Champion Rising you take control of an **everyday citizen** struggling to become a true superhero, with the dubious aid of the pompous **Blizzard Wizard**. **Create your own hero**, **train your superpowers** and **battle crooks and villains** in this **tongue-in-cheek hex based match-3** RPG.
>
> In you quest you will encounter supervillains, evil robots, corrupt government officials and heroes in need of anger management training - and much more. And who is the shadowy figure that Blizzard Wizard has been seen conspiring with? Solve the mystery by finding all the secrets in Vigilance Valley!

Several of the reviews mention a time limit. From the top review at the moment:

> Overall a fun game, but the main mission does have a 30 day in game time limit.

The screenshots clearly contain colored spheres on a hexagonal grid:

[image: A screenshot from Spandex Force: Champion Rising showing the player creating a combo and game text saying "Awesome!"]

While the game was removed from the [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.karjasoft.championrising) sometime after [2016](https://web.archive.org/web/20160207004301/https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.karjasoft.championrising) and its [original website](https://web.archive.org/web/20160528064613/http://www.spandexforce.com/) is down, it is also still available on [itch.io](https://karja.itch.io/spandex-force-champion-rising).

I found the game at the bottom of the first page of my search results for `superhero wizard match elements site:steampowered.com`

Comment: Huh. I found it on my Steam account and I'm pretty sure that they changed the mechanics to match the phone game because it was not Match-3 before.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like one review mentions that they might have replaced the game with a new version.

Comment: Eyeh, and based on the discussions, apparently that may have broken the Steam achievements because they replaced it with a version that doesn't have the multiple endings.